# File Reading and Variable Assignments

Tags: python, list, text, list-comprehension, filereader

So I am trying to make a game where the 'GameMaster' picks the first word from a .txt file, then the user tries to guess the word. Once the user correctly guess the word, the GameMaster looks to the next line in the file and the user has to guess again, so on and so forth...

The problem I am having, is getting the program to assign variables as the game continues. The program should iteratively look until there are no more words to choose from, whether that be 2 or infinity.

Since I don't have much experience working with file interaction in python, the best example I have is something like this:

file "input.txt" will contain:
dog
cat
bird
rat
mouse

And I am looking at what in in the .txt file with this:

```
def file_read():
with open ('/Users/someone/Desktop/input.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()
    for line in data:
        line.rstrip()
return data
```

Comment: And ... what is your question? You are already doing exactly that in `for line in data:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function returns the entire contents of the file, unaltered. `myfile.read()` returns the data from the file as a string. The `for` loop then iterates over every *character* in that string, not the lines. Furthermore, `rstrip()` operates only on each character. It does not affect the contents of `data` because `data` is an immutable string and the return value of `rstrip()` is not stored anywhere.

Something like this would better suit:

```
def file_read():
    with open('/Users/someone/Desktop/input.txt') as myfile:
        return [line.rstrip() for line in myfile]
```

This will return a *list* of the stripped lines from the file. Your word guessing code would then iterate over the list.

The above will work, however, it is not very efficient if the input file is large because all of the file would be read into memory to construct the list. A better way is to use a generator which yields a stripped line one at a time:

```
def file_read():
    with open('/Users/someone/Desktop/input.txt') as myfile:
        for line in myfile:
            yield line.rstrip()
```

Now that function is so simple, it seems pointless to bother with it. Your code could simply be:

```
with open('/Users/someone/Desktop/input.txt') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        user_guess_word(line.rstrip())
```

where `user_guess_word()` is a function that interacts with the user to guess what the word is, and returns once the guess it correct.

Answer (score 0):

This way uses `readlines` to get file contents in a `list` line by line. `readlines` returns a `list` containing lines.

Now iterate through `list` to check if user input matches with line content (which is a word in this case).

```
with open ('/Users/someone/Desktop/input.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    words = myfile.readlines()
    while x < len(words):
        if words[x] == input('Enter word to guess'):
            print('Predicted word correctly')
        else:
            print('Wrong word. Try again')
            x -= 1
        x += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like,

```
def fun():
    data = open('filename', 'r').readlines()
    user_guess, i = None, 0
    while i < len(data):
        user_guess = input()
        if user_guess not None and user_guess == data[i]:
            i = i + 1
```

Please trim() / strip() also while you compare user_guess and data[i]